# Mouse pointer automatically clicks on selection

Tags: mouse

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad X1Carbon (Gen 2) with dual boot - Ubuntu 16.04 and Win7. Recently I started having problems with the mouse/touchpad, and whereever the mouse pointer is on, after 1 or 2 seconds, it acts as if I clicked the mouse and it opens that particular file, app, link or whatever, almost immediately. It is the same if I use the touchpad, mouse or the red dot button in the middle of the keyboard. Disconnecting the mouse and/or turning off the touch pad makes no difference, the pointer still activates any selection made. At first I thought it was a hardware issue but then realized that it only acts this way in Ubuntu, the mouse/touchpad work fine in Win7. As suggested in a FB group, I tried updating the kernel but that didn't change anything. I also searched wiki.archlinux but could not find any similar problem there. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have set a condition under Universal Access to allow Hover Click.

Go to System Settings > Universal Access and ensure that Hover Lock is set to off as shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: OMG, that was it!!  I must have accidentally set that to ON when doing something else with the mouse settings..  Thank you so much!!  :)

Comment: @djgap Wonderful. Perhaps you would now be kind enough to vote the answer up as useful  and accept it so that it might help other users.

Comment: Sorry, I’m a bit new at this.. 

Comment: @djgap You'll get used to it! You can also upvote the answer as useful by clicking on the up arrow above the green tick. I've also upvoted your question. It's the way that reputation is earned on the site which builds privileges.